# Access violations on string operations in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, access-violation

I have a Delphi application that reads data form a file and stores it in an array. Each row in a file contains an address, lineTypeIndicator and data. This is the algorithm (contains code that I believe is critical):

```
AssignFile(inputFile, inFileName);
Reset(inputFile);
  while not EOF(inputFile) do
  begin
    Readln(inputFile,fileLineBuffer);        
     if  Copy(fileLineBuffer, 8, 2) = '01' then  //Never managed to catch the error here
    begin
      break;
    end;

    //extract the address from the line and use it to determine max and min address.
  end;

//Now that you have min and max address, use it to set the length of an char array
SetLength(memoryArray,(lastAddress - firstAddress) * 2);

Reset(inputFile);
  while not EOF(inputFile) do
  begin
    Readln(inputFile,fileLineBuffer);

     if  Copy(fileLineBuffer, 8, 2) = '01' then    //I caught all the errors here
    begin
      break;
    end;

    //extract the address and data from the fileLineBuffer and place it in the corresponding place in an array
  end;
```

This code is executed every time the user clicks the corresponding button on a form. It runs the first few times it is executed, but then after a few runs i get this:

> MyProgram.exe faulted with message: 'access violation at 0x00406111:
>   write of address 0x00090d1c (this varies). Proceess stopped. Use step
>   or run to continue.

To me, this smells like some kind of heap overflow. I have tried replacing

```
if  Copy(fileLineBuffer, 8, 2) = '01' then
```

with

```
lineTypeBuffer :=   Copy(fileLineBuffer, 8, 2);
if  lineTypeBuffer = '01' then
```

or

```
if  (fileLineBuffer[8] = '0') and (fileLineBuffer[9] = '1') then
```

but it did not help.
Any suggestions on how I should approach this problem?

P.S. Tried running it on Win7 32 bit and Win7 64 bit - no difference
P.P.S. sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only explanation for

```
Copy(fileLineBuffer, 8, 2) = '01'
```

resulting in an access violation is that you have corrupted the heap.

Something else in your program is writing out of bounds and corrupting the heap. Such problems can be tricky to diagnose because the fault is typically in one part of the code, but the error occurs elsewhere. Some code corrupts the heap, and then a subsequent heap operation fails because of the earlier heap corruption.

I am confident in my diagnosis because Delphi string variables are known to work, `Copy` is known to work, and string equality testing is known to work. In other words there is no fault in the line of code at which the error occurs. Ergo the error is elsewhere.

Some debugging tools that might help:

- FastMM in full debug mode.
- Range checking (enabled from the project's compiler options).

Comment: Thanks, this was correct. However I am not sure what to do regarding marking the answer as selected. There was a problem in 'place it in the corresponding place in an array'. The corresponding place happened to be out of bounds. As I am new to Delphi, I expected that I will get an exception as soon as the write happened. But the write succeeded and corrupted the heap. I you could integrate this in your answer I think it would be more useful to future readers so I could mark it as correct. Or I can write an answer myself. I prefer the 1st option since you were right you should get the credit :D

Comment: You can accept my answer. This sentence *Something else in your program is writing out of bounds and corrupting the heap* is what you are asking me to add. It's already there. Enabling range checking will have led you to the solution to your specific problem. There's no point me adding specifics of your problem, or you doing so, since they are not in the question. My answer is of a general nature. Step 1, the symptoms you describe can only be explain by heap corruption. Heap corruption happens elsewhere. Step 2, use debugging tools to locate that other point.

Comment: Anyway, I've added a couple of paragraphs giving some more info about the flavour of heap corruptions. I hope that improves the answer.

Comment: By the way, am I correct that you turned on range checking and the error was identified immediately? The range checking feature of the program is exceptionally powerful. I'm always amazed that it is not enabled by default.

Comment: Unfortunately range checking still does not work for me. I turned it on in project options but i still get the error in the same line (after heap corrupt). I expected it to notify me as soon as I try to write out of bounds. Am I right? The way I identified the error is by simply checking all index based writes for a few more times :D I was so fixated on the 'Copy' line that I ignored everything else - until you pointed me in the right direction that is.

Comment: That doesn't quite hang together. With range checking on, every array indexing operation is bounds checked. So, I don't understand how range checking would not trigger an exception at the point of corruption.

Comment: Functions like `Move` and `TStream.Read` can overwrite memory without detection by range checking. So can erroneous type casts, or string functions like `StrCpy`.

Comment: @RobKennedy In my case it is  myArray : array of char; myArray[indexOutOfBounds] := 'F';

Comment: Range checking will detect out of bounds accesses of that form